# Starting docker container results in docker-credential-secretservice: The connection is closed

Tags: docker, openstack-zuul

I'm trying to start the docker container from this tutorial (Quick-Start Installation and Tutorial): https://zuul-ci.org/docs/zuul/admin/quick-start.html#start-zuul-containers

```
WARNING: The no_proxy variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The http_proxy variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Building node
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.17.1', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 68, in main
    command()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 121, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 952, in up
    start=not no_start
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/project.py", line 431, in up
    svc.ensure_image_exists(do_build=do_build)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 318, in ensure_image_exists
    self.build()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 923, in build
    shmsize=parse_bytes(build_opts.get('shm_size')) if build_opts.get('shm_size') else None,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 238, in build
    self._set_auth_headers(headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 285, in _set_auth_headers
    self._auth_configs, registry
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/auth.py", line 97, in resolve_authconfig
    authconfig, registry, store_name
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/auth.py", line 142, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
    'Credentials store error: {0}'.format(repr(e))
docker.errors.DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('Credentials store docker-credential-secretservice exited with "The connection is closed".',)
```

What can possibly be causing this error? What is the solution for it?

I tried to reinstall docker-compose & docker.io, but no success.

Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I can't call it a solution really, but it helped me get rid of this problem and start the containers.

The steps are:

1. In `~/.docker/config.json` remove the line `"credsStore":"secretservice"`
2. `cd zuul/doc/source/admin/examples`
3. `sudo -E docker-compose up`

The containers should start now.

Comment: In my case, just remove `~/.docker/config.json` works after an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing Ivan. I had to do a `docker login` prior to your solution though, as I did not have a config.json file in my `~/.docker/.docker` directory.